# Flutter appbundle, icant fix :((

Tags: flutter

Flutter failed to write to a file at "C:\Users\mustafa\StudioProjects\Judge.flutter-plugins". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

How can i fix that. My pc is windows 8

[image]